# The child component is not called again if the component name is same

Tags: vue.js

I have a scenario where I have to call same component consecutively. First time when I call the component it loads but second time when I call the same component it doesn't reload the component.
I am using change state method to change the component.

```
    ChangeState: function (newState) {
      app.state = newState;
 },
```

If I call some other component in between then it works correctly. Please suggest how can i solve this issue.

Comment: Why are you "calling" components intead of using them in your app? Also more info about your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. it will work if $ is not supported.

```
Vue.nextTick(function() {
                        app.state = newState;
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't if Vue is watching for changes. One way around this is to set your state to `null`, then reset your component in the `nextTick`:

```
ChangeState(newState) {
  this.state = null;
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.state = newState;
  });
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1spj1hzv/

Your code is a bit strange though, what is `app`? You don't seem to be referring to any internal data property (like I have in my answer), but your question suggests that `app.state` is reactive, so you may need to tweak this answer for your particular use case.

Comment: Thanks your answer is helpful